# Codename one FontImage with resource Image

Tags: codenameone

I am developing a form where it has a list of users and profile images on the right.  Right now I have a default Multi image. I do not have a thumb nail and I decided to use the default image from resource but it's really huge on the screen.  I created a FontImage with fontsize 8 which is the perfect size.

1. Can I create a FontImage from an image from Multi Image?
2. If not how do I resize the image to fit to the size as to font size?
3. Any example of showing customer info on right and scaled profile
       image on the left to fit with right the information?

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the multi-image to any size you like using the `Image.scaled*()` methods.  E.g. to scale to the same height as your font image you would do something like:

```
Image resized = myMultiimage.scaledHeight(myFontImage.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Steve, I'll give it a try.